# Incremental Puzzle in C#

Tags: c#

In a race, you bet using the following strategy. Whenever you lose a bet, you double the value of the bet for the next round. Whenever you win, the bet for the next round will be one dollar. You start the round by betting one dollar.

For example, if you start with 20 dollars, and you win the bet in the first round, lose the bet in the next two rounds and then win the bet in the fourth round, you will end up with 20+1-1-2+4 = 22 dollars.

You are expected to complete the function, `getFinalAmount`, which takes two arguments:

1. The first argument is an integer `initialAmount` which is the initial money we amount we have when we start the betting.
2. The second argument is a string `betResults`. The ith character of outcome will be either 'W' (win) or 'L' (lose), denoting the result of the ith round.
   Your function should return the amount of money you will have after all the rounds are played.

If at some point you don't have enough money in your account to cover the value of the bet, you must stop and return the sum you have at that point.

I've tried this code and failed:

```
var amountInHand = 15;
var possiblities = "LLLWLLLL";

static int Calculate(int amountInHand, string possibles)
{
    var lastBet = 1;

    foreach (char c in possiblities)
    {
        if (c == 'W')
        {
            amountInHand = amountInHand + 1;
        }
        else if (c == 'L')
        {

            var loss = 0;
            if (lastBet == 1)
            {
                loss = lastBet;
            }
            else if (lastBet > 1)
            {
                loss = lastBet * 2;
            }
            amountInHand = amountInHand - loss;
            lastBet++;
        }
    }
    return amountInHand;
}
```

**Expected output**

```
1st round - Loss: 15-1 = 14
2nd round - Loss: 14-2 = 12 (Bet doubles)
3rd round - Loss: 12-4 = 8
4th round - Win: 8 + 8 = 16
5th round - Loss:16-1 = 15 (Since the previous bet was a win, this bet has a value of 1 dollar)
6th round - Loss: 15-2 = 13
7th round - Loss: 13-4 = 9
8th round - Loss: 9-8 = 1
```

Comment: why the `Java` tag for a `C#` question?

Comment: is this homework or interview question?

Comment: @Saurabh, Interview homework :)

Comment: @Saurabh, Sounds like it

Comment: You show 'Expected', what's missing is the 'Actual'. And the surrounding method (parameter, return).

Comment: Agree with Henk; first step is to add the prints to your code to "try" to get it to look like the "Expected", and see where yours goes wrong.

Comment: If it is an interview question, then you really need to answer it yourself.  If you get help here, you'll just be deceiving yourself and lining yourself up for problems if you get the job or further into the process.

Comment: ? Still don't see any "actual" output.  Try adding prints in your foreach loop that spits out all the variables, so you know where your loop is going wrong...

Comment: @PaulHadfield - both interview and homework questions are allowed, but they should be treated a little different.

Comment: -1 for just "it failed" without further explanation.

Comment: @Henk, I know that, but would you like to hire / work with somebody that couldn't do a simple exercise but got it answered instead on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @PaulHadfield - or by a friend, in private? You'll have to talk to them anyway.

Comment: I got this as a interview question recently, so that's the source.  I solved it in a Linq one liner, but have it at home.  I'll try and remember to post it tonight.

Comment: It's an interview question.  I got the same one several months ago.  I came up with a handful of solutions that I'm going to use for blog fodder tonight.  I'll post an answer and xref the blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct answer given by R.B. But dont know why he deleted.

```
      var amountInHand = 15;

        var possiblities = "LLLWLLLL";
        var lastBet = 1;



        foreach (char c in possiblities)
        {
            if (c == 'W')
            {
                amountInHand = amountInHand + lastBet;
                lastBet = 1;
            }
            else if (c == 'L')
            {
                amountInHand = amountInHand - lastBet;
                lastBet = lastBet * 2;
            }
            //handle running out of money
            if (lastBet > amountInHand) return amountInHand;
        }
```

Comment: Ahh, but does it quit if/when you run out of money?  :P

Comment: The above answer is NOT correct.  I'm going to revive this question as blog fodder this evening.

Comment: Why you said @Billa is wrong? Can you explain what's wrong? I see the replier didn't included the condition if the money ends. Anything else?

Comment: The money ending isn't covered.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a [blog post](http://www.smokingcode.com/2014/04/solving-programming-puzzle-with-lambda.html) and a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26236/incremental-puzzle-in-c) about this question.  My answer is this, and indeed it works...:

```
return possibilities.Aggregate(new{b=1,c=amountInHand,x=1},(l,o)=>l.x<0?l:o=='W'?new{b=1,c=l.c+l.b,x=1}:new{b=l.b*2,c=l.c-l.b,x=(l.c-l.b)-(l.b*2)}).c;
```

Un-golfed:

```
private static int getFinalAmount(string q, int w)
{
    return possibilities.Aggregate(new { b = 1, c = amountInHand, x = false }, //initial seed gets the flag for cancel set to false
                    (l, o) =>
        l.x     //if our cancel flag is set, 
            ? l      //just return the same result
            : o == 'W'   //if the outcome was a win
                        //do the math and now also set a cancel flag to false (if we won, we can make our next bet for sure)
                ? new { b = 1, c = l.c + l.b, x = false }
                        //do our math again, but this time the cancel flag is tricky.  
                : new { b = l.b * 2, c = l.c - l.b,
                                //we cancel if our new amount will be less than our new bet.  
                                //Note, we can't use the new values that we just set in the same section - 
                                //they're not available yet so we have duplicate math here.
                            x = (l.c - l.b) < (l.b * 2) })
                    .c;   //all the function returns is the current amount
}
```